# Almost everywhere convergence does not imply uniform convergence.

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure, uniform-convergence

By definition, a sequence of functions $f_n$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere in a set $D$ if $m(\left\{x\in D \text{ such that } f_n(x) \text{ does not converge to } f(x)\right\}) = 0$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. My question here is how do we relate this kind of definition to uniform convergence?

Can we show by example that almost everywhere convergence doesn't imply uniform convergence?
In other words, an example of a sequence of functions that converges almost everywhere but does not converge uniformly, and why it fails to converge uniformly.

Comment: Why do you want relate this convergence with the uniform converge ? Obviously, a.e. convergence won't implies uniform convergence since it's a much stronge convergence. Unifom convergence $\implies $ pointwise convergence $\implies $ a.e. convergence, but the converse are wrong.

Comment: The sequence $\{\chi_{[n,n+1]}\}_n$ converge pointwise to $0$, but it does not converge uniformly.

Comment: Thanks, it does answer the question, but why did the sequence fail uniform convergence?

Comment: In his question, he is interested in a sequence that converge almost everywhere but not almost uniform? I am interested in sequence that converge almost everywhere but not uniformly

Comment: If a sequence of function does not converge almost uniformly then, trivially, it does not converge uniformly. So your question is clearly contained in 
the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894298/sequence-of-sets-f-n-that-converge-almost-everywhere-to-f-but-not-almost-uni .

In that question, 
the answer gives as an example : "Take $f=1$ and $f_n=\chi_{[-n,n]}$". 

Do you need help checking that $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $f$ ?

Comment: Another easy example is $g_n=\chi_{[n,n+1]}$, which converges pointwise to $0$ and so it converges almost everywhere to $0$ but it does not converge uniformly to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

There are sequences of functions that converge everywhere (not just almost) but not uniformly.  For instance on the interval (0,1) take $f_n = \min(n,1/x)$.  $f_n$ converge to $1/x$ everywhere, but not uniformly.